# Single Board Computer with Pci-Express

Tags: debian, arm, single-board

Does amdgpu and radeon drivers exist on platforms like armhf and arm64 for single board computers with PCI-Express slots?

I'm asking if they exist because I wouldn't think they'd have the graphics driver for a non x86 or x86_64 computer

Comment: Both drivers are for AMD graphics. Why would they "exist" for hardware that isn't AMD? I suspect your actual question is about something else. What's the problem you're trying to solve? Please [edit] the question instead of replying in comments.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: What do you mean, "hardware that isn't AMD"? It seems that OP is asking specifically about AMD video cards. (Just because the CPU architecture isn't x86 **does not** mean that it cannot have a PCI bus, allowing this was actually part of the PCI design.)

Comment: If you have links to or the exact brand/model of affordable ARM motherboards with PCIe slots (plural), I would be very interested, because I've been looking for those for some time.

Answer (score 1):

> I wouldn't think they'd have the graphics driver for a non x86 or x86_64 computer

The 'amdgpu' and 'radeon' drivers are part of the Linux kernel. DRM_AMDGPU on the Linux kernel declares only dependencies on `DRM && PCI && MMU`; this implies that it is supported on any architecture that has PCI.

Arch Linux ARM [includes](https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/aarch64/linux-aarch64/files/config) both 'amdgpu' and 'radeon' drivers in their AArch64 kernel (although not their other armvX kernels).